How can I make the object not move the wrong way?
I am learning to use Game Maker, and I thought it would be a good project to make some basic plane movement script. I finished the part that would move the plane and then added the part that would make the plane glide slowly to a halt. The issue is that whenever I press the down arrow key, the plane will move, but it will glide to a halt moving up, not down. Here is the code. Note: plane_speed = 0,  plane_acceleration = 0.1.
// Check keyboard input for up and down keys
keyboard_up = keyboard_check(vk_up);
keyboard_down = keyboard_check(vk_down);

// Adjust plane speed based on keyboard input and switch costumes
if keyboard_up == 1 {
    plane_speed = plane_speed + plane_acceleration;
    y -= plane_speed;  // Move plane up (assuming y is decreasing moves up)
    sprite_index = Sprite3;  // Change sprite to Sprite3 when moving up
}

if keyboard_down == 1 {
    plane_speed = plane_speed + plane_acceleration;
    y += plane_speed;  // Move plane down (assuming y is increasing moves down)
    sprite_index = sPlane;  // Change sprite to sPlane when moving down
}

if keyboard_down == 0 && keyboard_up == 0
    if plane_speed != 0 {
        if (plane_speed > 0) {
            plane_speed = plane_speed - plane_acceleration;
            y -= plane_speed;
        }
        if (plane_speed < 0) {
            plane_speed = plane_speed + plane_acceleration;
            y -= plane_speed;
        }

    }

I have tried to switch around some of the plus and minus signs, but it will just make everything worse. Is it possible that I should switch the order of my code, is it a bug, or is it something else?

I believe the problem is that plane_speed will only ever be positive when adjusted by the keyboard inputs in the code provided.
...
if keyboard_up == 1 {
    plane_speed = plane_speed + plane_acceleration; // speed is positive.
    ...
}

if keyboard_down == 1 {
    plane_speed = plane_speed + plane_acceleration; // speed is positive.
    ...
}
...

Try modifying the "keyboard_up adjustment" section as follows:
if keyboard_up == 1 {
    plane_speed = plane_speed - plane_acceleration;
    y += plane_speed;
    ...
}

This way, when keyboard_up == 1, plane_speed will go negative, and this negative value will be added to y (effectively subtracting from y).
Edit: As user @ipodtouch0218 pointed out, if the plane is only ever supposed to glide downwards when decelerating, you'll also need to make this change:
...
if (plane_speed < 0) {
    plane_speed = plane_speed + plane_acceleration;
    y += plane_speed;
}

If it helps, you can envision this as two cases:

Plane goes up (plane_speed is negative, y is negative), now plane decelerates & goes down (plane_speed increases, y increases).

Plane goes down (plane_speed is positive, y is positive), now plane decelerates & goes down (plane_speed decreases, y increases)



This is a little off-topic, and I apologize if I'm stepping out of my lane here since I don't know your game, but I'd like to point out that you may want to cap the plane's speed at some arbitrary value. (i.e. don't add to it if it's already a big positive number, and don't subtract from it if it's already a big negative number). Otherwise, the player might be able to reach ludicrous speeds by holding a keyboard input down. If this is already accounted for, please disregard.

This is correct, but do note that they would also need to change their deceleration code later down, as they do y -= plane_speed;, not +=

@ipodtouch0218 Nice catch, thank you! Post edited.
